# [Golang]: How can I check if a K8s node is part of an ETCD cluster?

Tags: go, kubernetes, etcd

I know I can use client-go to programmatically check metadata about the node such as it's status. But how can I check if it is an active part of an ETCD cluster programmatically?

The equivalent action to this would be to ssh into the node and use `etcdctl` but I was wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: if you mean `client-go` as in the kubernetes client, no, not that I'm aware of unless etcd is running as a pod (meaning `kubectl get po -A | grep etcd-` returns something). If you have access to the actual node, e.g. `ssh $the_node sh -c "ps auwx | grep etcd"`, then that can help you, but etcd is not supposed to be exposed to the kubernetes workloads (i.e. `kubectl` ) since that's a security risk. What have you already tried and what outcome is it producing for you? Put another way, how would you know if a solution was successful in _your setup_?